# how to align dotfill in a wrapped line

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable

how to align dotfill and square symbol in a longtable with wrapped lines?

I wrote this mwe:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\lsquare}{\Large\Square}
\newcommand{\lcheck}{\Large\CheckedBox}

\begin{longtable}{@{\hspace{1cm}}p{12cm}<{\dotfill}>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{1cm}}
    \caption{Criteria for risk classification of petrol filling stations according vicinity}
    \label{tab:criteria}\\

    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textbf{Yes/No} \\   \midrule

    \endfirsthead

    \caption{Criteria for risk classification of petrol filling stations according vicinity (continuation)}\\


    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textbf{Yes/No} \\\midrule

    \endhead

    \midrule

    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{\footnotesize continues on the next page}} \\ 

    \endfoot
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Classification of petrol filling station:}\\ 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\hfill \small{0} \lsquare \hfill \small{1} \lsquare \hfill \small{2} \lsquare \hfill \small{3} \lcheck}\\

    \bottomrule

    \endlastfoot



\multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Class 0} \\\cmidrule(r{9cm}){1-1}

There are none of the worsening factors of the following classes & \lsquare \\

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Class 1} \\\cmidrule(r{9cm}){1-1}


Rainwater drainage network & \lcheck \\
Underground service network (water, sewage, telephone, electricity, etc.) & \lcheck \\
Septic tank in urban areas & \lsquare \\
Multi-family building with four floors & \lsquare \\
Asylum & \lsquare \\
Nursery & \lsquare \\

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Class 2} \\\cmidrule(r{9cm}){1-1}
Multifamily building with more than four floors & \lsquare \\
Slum in elevation equal to or greater than the rank & \lsquare \\
Commercial office building with four or more floors & \lsquare \\
Well of water, artesian or not for domestic consumption & \lsquare \\
House of shows or temple & \lsquare \\
School & \lsquare \\
Hospital &  \lsquare \\


\multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Class 3} \\\cmidrule(r{9cm}){1-1}

Slum in lower quota than the petrol fuel station & \lsquare \\
Subway at lower level than the ground & \lsquare \\
Residential or commercial building built on a plot below ground & \lsquare \\
Tunnel below ground level & \lsquare \\
Residential, commercial or industrial building built in lower ground level & \lsquare \\
Industrial activities and risk operations  & \lsquare \\
Subsoil water used to elevate the city's perimeter & \lcheck \\

\multicolumn{1}{p{13cm}}{\hspace{0.7cm} Superficial natural bodies of water to:} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\

%\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{0.5cm}}p{12cm}c}
\hspace{0.5cm} Domestic Supply & \lsquare \\
\hspace{0.5cm} Aquatic Community Protection & \lsquare \\
\hspace{0.5cm} Contact Recreation (swimming, water skiing and diving) & \lsquare \\
\hspace{0.5cm} Irrigation & \lsquare \\
\hspace{0.5cm} Natural and intensive food production for human (National Environment Council (NEC) 20/2010) & \lsquare \\
%\end{tabular}

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

change `p` to `b`

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\lsquare}{\Large\Square}
\newcommand{\lcheck}{\Large\CheckedBox}

\begin{longtable}{@{\hspace{1cm}}b{12cm}<{\dotfill}>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{1cm}}
    \caption{Criteria for risk classification of petrol filling stations according vicinity}
    \label{tab:criteria}\\

    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textbf{Yes/No} \\   \midrule

    \endfirsthead

    \caption{Criteria for risk classification of petrol filling stations according vicinity (continuation)}\\


    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textbf{Yes/No} \\\midrule

    \endhead

    \midrule

    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{\footnotesize continues on the next page}} \\ 

    \endfoot
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Classification of petrol filling station:}\\ 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\hfill \small{0} \lsquare \hfill \small{1} \lsquare \hfill \small{2} \lsquare \hfill \small{3} \lcheck}\\

    \bottomrule

    \endlastfoot



\multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Class 0} \\\cmidrule(r{9cm}){1-1}

There are none of the worsening factors of the following classes & \lsquare \\

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Class 1} \\\cmidrule(r{9cm}){1-1}


Rainwater drainage network & \lcheck \\
Underground service network (water, sewage, telephone, electricity, etc.) & \lcheck \\
Septic tank in urban areas & \lsquare \\
Multi-family building with four floors & \lsquare \\
Asylum & \lsquare \\
Nursery & \lsquare \\

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Class 2} \\\cmidrule(r{9cm}){1-1}
Multifamily building with more than four floors & \lsquare \\
Slum in elevation equal to or greater than the rank & \lsquare \\
Commercial office building with four or more floors & \lsquare \\
Well of water, artesian or not for domestic consumption & \lsquare \\
House of shows or temple & \lsquare \\
School & \lsquare \\
Hospital &  \lsquare \\


\multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Class 3} \\\cmidrule(r{9cm}){1-1}

Slum in lower quota than the petrol fuel station & \lsquare \\
Subway at lower level than the ground & \lsquare \\
Residential or commercial building built on a plot below ground & \lsquare \\
Tunnel below ground level & \lsquare \\
Residential, commercial or industrial building built in lower ground level & \lsquare \\
Industrial activities and risk operations  & \lsquare \\
Subsoil water used to elevate the city's perimeter & \lcheck \\

\multicolumn{1}{p{13cm}}{\hspace{0.7cm} Superficial natural bodies of water to:} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\

%\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{0.5cm}}p{12cm}c}
\hspace{0.5cm} Domestic Supply & \lsquare \\
\hspace{0.5cm} Aquatic Community Protection & \lsquare \\
\hspace{0.5cm} Contact Recreation (swimming, water skiing and diving) & \lsquare \\
\hspace{0.5cm} Irrigation & \lsquare \\
\hspace{0.5cm} Natural and intensive food production for human (National Environment Council (NEC) 20/2010) & \lsquare \\
%\end{tabular}

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it easy for the dotfill command to complete up to the symbol? @david-carlisle

Comment: @leonardocesar you are forcing the final column to be final column to be 1cm wiide which is a lot wider than the symbol, so there is a gap, you could replace `>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{1cm}` by `@{}c` so that column is as wide as the content with no inter-column space (and hide the width of the heading)